# When creating a nested dictionary of dataframes, how can I name a dictionary based on a list name of the dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When creating a nested dictionary of dataframes, how can I name a dictionary based on a list name of the dataframe?

Given the following:

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla'],
        'Price': [22000,25000]
        }

df_cars = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand','Price'])

trucks = {'Brand': ['GMC Sierra','Ford F-150'],
        'Price': [50000,48000]
        }

df_trucks = pd.DataFrame(trucks, columns = ['Brand','Price'])


list_of_dfs = [df_cars, df_trucks]

# Not exactly sure how this code should be: 
dict_of_dfs = {}
for df in list_of_dfs:
    dict_of_dfs[name_of_df] = {}
    dict_of_dfs[name_of_df]['results'] = df
```

I am trying to use a for loop to result in the following:

```
dict_of_dfs['df_cars'] = {}    
dict_of_dfs['df_cars']['results'] = df_cars
dict_of_dfs['df_trucks'] = {}
dict_of_dfs['df_trucks']['results'] = df_trucks
```

which should produce a desired output such as the following:

```
{
    'df_cars': {
        'results':             
        Brand  Price
        0 Honda Civic  22000
        1 Toyota Corolla  25000}, 

    'df_trucks': {
        'results':        
         Brand  Price
        0  GMC Sierra  50000
        1  Ford F-150  48000}
}
```

I've read multiple threads, used the module `varname`, and tried using `enumerate()` but have been unsuccessful.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Why don't you update the dict when dataframe's are created, why is a loop required ?

Comment: I tried to simplify my original problem but inadvertently left out a few lines.  I updated the question to reflect the desired output based on the commands I am trying to emulate with the for loop.  @Ch3steR

Comment: @Sushanth - I'm using a loop because I would rather not type out this stuff individually?  If there is a better way to do this, then there is a very high chance that I don't know it.